# Is Git the solution for syncing files between the entire team?

Tags: git

We're a team of developers cooperating on a project. We work in a shared folder we manage ourselves and upload to various FTP servers when we have it the way we want it.

We don't currently have any way to record  what was changed, or when or by who. Sometimes one of us has to work from outside of the office, leading to out-of-sync files,
then too often we copy those files back into the shared directory and from there on to the FTP server.

This setup is plainly wrong, and we think Git might be able to solve our problems or at least help, but none of us has any experience with Git.  Is this really something Git can do, simply enough that we can understand it and manage it ourselves?

Comment: Sounds like a version control system as Git is what you need

Comment: Sounds like a Distributed Version Control System is what you need. Git is one of them, but you may prefer Mercurial, Fossil or even Bazaar.

Comment: There's no indication here of what OP has read.  Voting to close as "too broad", to supply OP's wants would require supplying a summary of much basic documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly what git was designed to do. More generally, any distributed revision control system would serve your use case. There is a learning curve, but version control is a must for any group of developers working collaboratively on a project.

Answer (score 0):

Any version control software will help you, svn, git, etc...

I'm not familiar with git, but You can use svn repository, if you have shell access to server you can use your repository for everyday work and finally use shell access to update directory on server. Even if not svn will resolve a lot of problems.

Comment: Not sure how well SVN would work, given the OP's statement that "sometimes one of us has to work from outside of the office, leading to out-of-sync files", implying that developers working from out of the office wouldn't have access to the SVN server.

Comment: Git is better for work offline, but still with svn you can work out of office and commit your changes later.